# How to open SharePoint site in ipad without clicking on "Switch to PC View"?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Whenever i open SharePoint online site in Ipad mini first it's shows me the all libraries and lists after that when i click on "..." this icon and click on Switch to pc view after it shows me site's home page.

is there any way to directly load site's homepage? without switching to PC view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to deactivate the `Mobile browser view` feature so that users are redirected straight to homepage.

1) In you site, go to Site Settings > Manage site features

URL would be like https://siteurl/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx

2) Find Mobile browser view

3) Deactivate it.

4) Once done, just refresh the site again in the mobile browser and you will be redirected to the site's welcome page.

[image]